# How to return an array?

Tags: swift

I am trying to return an array with all the variables. So I can store everything inside an array.
How can I fix my code so that it puts everything into an array?

```
func getFriendRecord () -> [String] {
    var info = ""
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Friend> = Friend.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
        for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
            let firstName = String(trans.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String)
            let lastName = String(trans.value(forKey: "lastName") as! String)
            let gender = String(trans.value(forKey: "gender") as! String)
            let age = String(trans.value(forKey: "age") as! String)
            let address = String(trans.value(forKey: "address") as! String)
            info = info + firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + gender + ", " + age + ", " + address + "\n"
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
    return info
}
```

Comment: Returning an array is a bad idea. You should define a struct with appropriate fields and return that.

Comment: Unrelated but there's little sense in combing the use of `String( ... )` with `as! String`. A line such as `let firstName = trans.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String` is enough.

Comment: You need to create one array of string and add "info" (String) to that array, because your function return type is [String].

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return an array, then `info` should be an array:

```
var info: [String] = []
```

And then you'll add additional elements to that array:

```
let record = [firstName, lastName, gender, age, address].joined(separator: ", ") + "\n"
info.append(record)
```

I've changed this to a `joined` because you should avoid having multiple `+` in an expression. In Swift, for non-obvious reasons related to overloads, it is *extremely* slow to compile. There's nothing wrong with it, it just doesn't work well. You could also just use string interpolation here, and that would be completely fine (possibly even a little better):

```
let record = "\(firstName), \(lastName), \(gender), \(age), \(address)\n"
```

Comment: Dude you are a god. I fixed it using your thing. OMG you are the smartest person in the world. Thank you so much! I love you!

Answer (score 0):

You should define a struct and then you  could return it and append in an array.

```
    struct Info {
      var firstName: String?
      var lastName: String?
      var gender: String?
      var age: String?,
      var adress: String?
    }
```

And then you can use this struct.

```
    var info  : [Info] = []
    func getFriendRecord () {
        var info = ""
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Friend> = Friend.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
            for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
                let firstName = trans.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String
                let lastName = trans.value(forKey: "lastName") as! String
                let gender = trans.value(forKey: "gender") as! String
                let age = trans.value(forKey: "age") as! String
                let address = trans.value(forKey: "address") as! String
                let information = Info(firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,gender:gender,age:age,adress:adress)
                self.info.append(information)

            }
        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }
    }
```